# Spin a picture on touch event with timer

Tags: android, timer, touch-event

I am trying to spin a picture with a timer on touch event. I created a method which works without timer/thread. But When I use it in a timer, It doesnt work. I am not good in android programming.

-----------> this is the ontouch event

@Override

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){

 t1=new TimerTask()
{                

 public void run()
 {                              

  angle += 40; 
  spin(angle);
  if(angle >=360)
  angle = 0;
 }
 };

t.schedule(t1,2*1000);

return false;
}});
```

----------> and this is my spin method

```
public void spin(int degree)
{
  Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
  Matrix mat = new Matrix();
  mat.postRotate(degree);
  Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap, 0, 0, bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight(), mat, true);
  bottle.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `android.os.Handler` instead of your timer like this-

```
@override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
             angle += 40; 
              spin(angle);
              if(angle >=360)
              angle = 0;
        }
    }, 2*1000);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your attention. I want it to works a few times.. I mean, I need some kind of loop..

Comment: Then you can use the same code in combination with `android.os.Looper` and loop it as many times as you want with Looper.loop()

Comment: thanx for answering.. Its ok :) And also I solved it too.. here is my code.. http://pastebin.com/T2KKrk5z